# Android NDK: Problems building library depending on a prebuilt one

Tags: android, linker, android-ndk

I have a c library called B and it depends on other c library called A. I am sure I can successfully compile and use A through Android NDK.

Now I am trying to compile the B library using Android NDK. I have and Android project with a jni folder. My jni folder contains the A and B folders, they have the libraries c code. The jni folder also has a prebuilt folder, and it contains the a.so file (the prebuilt A library file).

My problem is that I can not build the B. I can compile it, but I cannot link it. Please, could anyone help me pointing what would be my mistake? A and B are generic names I am using to my projects, not the real ones I am using. I will list below the Android.mk files.

The Android.mk file used to build A (this file is not visible to the Android Project I described, although it has also the A code):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := helloworld.c A/src/fileA.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/src
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/src
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

The Android.mk file in the prebuilt folder:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libA
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := prebuilt/libA.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/A/src
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libB
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := B/src/fileB.c
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libA
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

When I execute the ndk-build command I have the final output to be something like:

> B/src/fileB.c:15: error: undefined reference to
>   'A_function' collect2: ld returned 1 exit status make: ***
>   [obj/local/armeabi/libB.so] Error 1

Answer (score 0):

Your B library files can actually access the A library, but they just don't know how. Add the required headers (.h files from the A library) to a subfolder of JNI and specify the following :

```
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/your/sub/folder
```

in your B project declaration.

I still had a problem, and had to declare the A library as PREBUILT_STATIC and then add to the B library

```
LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libA
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering it. But, please, do you mean I should modify the Android.mk file of the jni folder in my Android Project to compile B so it would not have the "LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := libA" clause? If so, I am sorry to say it did not solve the problem yet. I already have something like $(LOCAL_PATH)/your/sub/folder, it is my A/src folder and the LOCAL_C_INCLUDES seems to not have effect because of the LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES set in the B project Android.mk file.

Comment: I'm saying you hsould replace the LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES with LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES.